How to define channel name with model_type/model_id parameters?
On laravel / livewire site I use soketi, which I added with command :
npm install -g @soketi/soketi

and sending events I use separate channel for model/Id, like :
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\ChatMessage;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewChatMessageEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public ChatMessage $chatMessage;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct(ChatMessage $chatMessage)
    {

        $this->chatMessage = $chatMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        $channel = 'chat_messages.';
        $a = \Str::of($this->chatMessage->model_type)->explode('\\');
        if(count($a) === 3) {
            $channel .= $a[2] . '.' . $this->chatMessage->model_id; // I USE channel name with such name as any model/id would have a separate channel
        }
        return [
            new PrivateChannel($channel),
        ];
    }
}

But in routes/channels I have :
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) { // TODO
    dd(' -1 INSIDE Broadcast::channel $user->id::'); // IS NOT CALLED
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id; // IS NOT CALLED
});

// I am not sure if I need somehow to define chat_messages event
//Broadcast::channel('chat_messages.NNN.X', function (User $user) {
//    return true;
//});

In docs at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting
I see an example :
Echo.private(`chat.${roomId}`)
    .whisper('typing', {
        name: this.user.name
    });

That is not clear for me where from I need to use roomId var - in my case model_type/model_id ?
In routes/channels I have not any model_type/model_id paremeters and in resources/js/bootstrap.js having line :
window.Echo.private("chat_messages.NNN.X").listen("NewChatMessageEvent",(e)=>{
    console.log(e);
})

In my app only staff of the site (users having rows in spatie permissions tables) have access to these chats, the rest of users have no this access?
How to make it ?
DETAILS BLOCK :
Firstly I made chat with only chat name, without any modelType/modelId, as my chat_messages table has
model_type and model_id fields
in routes/channels.php I made:
Broadcast::channel('chat_messages', function (User $user) {
    return true;
});

and chat works ok
I try to remade with modelType/modelId
in routes/channels.php I made:
Broadcast::channel('chat_messages.{modelType}.{modelId}', function (User $user, int $orderId) {
    return true;
});

I did not change anything in app/Livewire/Admin/UsersChat.php with lines:
#[On('echo-private:chat_messages,NewChatMessageEvent')]
public function onNewChatMessageEvent($data)
    {

not sure if I have to change something in this code ...
I remade app/Events/NewChatMessageEvent.php :
public function broadcastOn(): array
{
    $channel = 'chat_messages.';
    $a = \Str::of($this->chatMessage->model_type)->explode('\\');
    if(count($a) === 3) {
        $channel .= $a[2] . '.' . $this->chatMessage->model_id;
    }

    return [
        new PrivateChannel($channel),
    ];
}

So name of the channel must be like
chat_messages.Task.7

I left file resources/js/bootstrap.js as it is:
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'mt1',
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ? import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST : `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
NewChatMessageEvent.php, app/Livewire/Admin/UsersChat.php */

window.Echo.private("chat_messages").listen("NewChatMessageEvent",(e)=>{
    console.log(e);
})

not sure if I have to change something in this code ...
But now I got an error :
POST                    http://localhistingsite.com/broadcasting/auth [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 554ms]

What is wrong ?
"laravel/framework": "^10.48.7",
"livewire/livewire": "^3.4.10",
"pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.2",
"spatie/laravel-permission": "^6.4"

Thanks in advance!

You are using laravel 10 so consider using Laravel Reverb

Do you mean that @soketi/soketi is a bad choice, but reverb is a good choice? If so , please explain why...

Please read DETAILS BLOCK

i'am not sure if t=it's bad choice or not, but reverb is a laravel solution so it will be easy to integrate it with your laravel project
